# Не могу нажать на элемент по css селектору. Но если прописываю полный xpath до кнопки - она нажимается. Selenium webdriver 2.53

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver

Мой пример css:

```
"a[data-action='completeOffer']"
```

Xpath

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a
```

При попытке отработать по css у меня появляется ошибка

> ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

Comment: Не описывайте столь подробно проблему в заголовке. Используйте обрамление одинарными кавычками ` для выделения небольшой части кода, клавишу `{}` или отступы в четыре пробела для выделения большой части кода.

Answer (score 2):

Убедитесь, что по вашему селектору находится только один веб элемент и что селектор указывает именно на видимую его часть